# why doesn't this autocmd take effect for neovim?

Tags: neovim, autocmd

I am writing an autocmd which will warn me if the file opened is not in UTF-8 format. This is what I have got:

```
augroup non_utf8_file
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufRead * if &fileencoding != 'utf-8' | echomsg 'file not in utf-8 format!' | endif
augroup END
```

Unfortunately, the above autocmd does not work in Neovim when I tried to open a file which is not utf-8 encoded. No message is shown.

But if I open the same file in Vim using the above settings, the warning message is shown correctly.

### Version info:

- Neovim: 0.4.0
- Vim: 7.4

Comment: What's the output of the command `:verbose set fileencodings?` when run in Neovim and Vim?

Comment: If I only use the above settings and nothing else, the output is `fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1`  both for neovim and vim.

Comment: What's the output of `:verbose set fileencoding?` for the non-UTF-8 file in Neovim?

Comment: the output for `:verbose set fileencoding?` inside neovim is `fileencoding=latin1`.

Comment: Any chance the message is just being dismissed before you get a chance to see it? Is it in `:messages`?

Comment: No, when I use `:messages`, it shows nothing.

Comment: @jdhao Try to prefix `:echom` with `:unsilent`; i.e. `unsilent echomsg 'file not in utf-8 format!'`

Comment: @user938271 Thanks, it works now!! But why does this different behavior between Vim and Neovim?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Nvim. I tried to find more information from the issue tracker, and only found [this issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8675). FWIW, because of the last issue, I never test whether a piece of code is processed via `:echom` but via a counter (`let g:counter = get(g:, 'counter', 0) + 1`). If `g:counter` exists, your piece of code was processed. The benefit of the counter is it can also tell you how many times it was processed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It seems the reason. If I remove `F` flag from `shortmess` option, it seems that this issue is fixed.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't read the issue properly. It seems that Nvim added the flag `F` in the `'shortmess'` option in [this commit](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/b7514493a0c4a4389a5921f15b0b429dae5c75e7).

Comment: @Rich, I will write one.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is caused by the `F` flag in the `shortmess` option<sup>[1]</sup>. If you remove the `F` flag from `shortmess`, you can see the displayed message
correctly. This issue has been filled as [#8675](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8675) and [#9870](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/9870).

As an alternative, if you change the autocmd event from `BufRead` to `BufEnter`
or `BufWinEnter`, the message can be shown without removing the `F` flag.

I have also filed [an issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/10008) in
the Neovim GitHub repo. The developer says that it is an internal implementation
and didn't give the reason for this behavior.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Thanks to [user938271](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/17449/user938271)
for pointing out that the `F` flag is added in [this neovim commit](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/b7514493a0c4a4389a5921f15b0b429dae5c75e7).